# adf declarative component custom methods queueEvent() not working

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using Oracle ADF JDev 12.1.3

I have a custom declarative LOV component and one custom method "valueChangeEvent",
after user select some values from the popup, i will do some validations, if all validations are ok, then I need to raise "valueChangeEvent" event,
so that in the final jspx page additional logic's can be implemented,

My declarative component method definition as follows

```
           <method-attribute>
                <attribute-name>
                    valueChangeListener
                </attribute-name>
                <method-signature>
                    java.lang.Void method(javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent)
                </method-signature>
                <required>
                    false
                </required>
            </method-attribute>
```

In my custom LOV Component, i have one input text and button, I tried the following to invoke my custom method within the command button action, but it does not invoke the event at the main form, but no error shows

```
// get the component reference using Face Context ValueExpression 
_this = getThisDeclarativeCompoent();
//try to queue the valueChangeEvent - but this does not work
_this.queueEvent(new ValueChangeEvent(_this, NewValue, OldValue));
```

Consuming application code is as follows

```
<af:declarativeComponent viewId="/ASGLOVBrowser.jspx" id="dc3" label="Modules" LOV_Name="MODULE"
                                     bindingAttribute="#{bindings.ModuleId}" showDescription="true"
                                     multiSelect="false" matchingField="CODE"
                                     valueChangeListener="#{viewScope.DeclarativeTestBean.test_valueChangeEvent}"/>
```

appreciate if someone can help...

Comment: This code you have listed above, where exactly does it sit? I am struggling to make sense of your question here.

Comment: thanks florin for looking in to this, In my custom LOV Component, i have one input text and button, I tried these code to invoke my custom method within the command button action...modified my question to make it more clear...

Answer (score 0):

Value Change event is raised by the framework only, when input value changes, therefore you can't initiate the event without the value being changed either from UI or programatically.

So, you can get a reference of the input text UIComponent and change the value programatically:

```
RichInputText uiComp = <<<get reference>>>;
uiComp.setValue(newValue);
```

Comment: thanks Florin for the suggestion, but my requirement was to send some events from the Declarative Component to the consuming page, on completion of some short processing. Temporarily i managed to use an action event method in the declarative component with a hidden button hooked in to that, and then button binding have been used to invoke this action using 'queueEvent'.